# How to turn off persistent connections for web service calls

Tags: c#, web-services, session, proxy, asmx

From my WinForms application I have to call a webservice and I am using a web reference for that. No problems so far, but now I have a client that uses the software behind a proxy that is behind a load balancer.

Webservice calls are going fine, but after two minutes they fail. We can work around this by repeatedly calling a webservice with an interval less than two minutes.

I turns out that the load balancer disconnects tcp sessions when they are not used for two minutes, appearantly this is what happens in our case and the sofware is unable to recover.

How do I tell the gerenated web reference to use a new tcp connection for every web service call?

Comment: Are you disposing of the proxy objects in between calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you override the `GetWebRequest` method of your proxy, then you can set the `KeepAlive` property:

```
public override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) base.GetWebRequest(uri);
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    return request;
}
```

Comment: I can turn off the KeepAlive on the webrequest, but I keep seeing Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive in the headers.

Comment: @fordan: that would be for the web proxy, not for the main connection. I don't know how to change that, or what makes it turn on.