# How to turn off persistent proxy connections

Tags: c#, web-services, session, proxy, asmx

This is a follow up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933383/how-to-turn-off-persistent-connections-for-web-service-calls) on how to turn of `Connection: Keep-Alive` headers on `HttpWebRequest`.

I have successfully disabled the `Connection: Keep-Alive` headers from my Web service call, but when I use a proxy it also sends a `CONNECT xxx.xxxxx.xx:443 HTTP/1.1` to the proxy before the call is sent to the server.

With this `CONNECT` call a bunch of headers are sent:

`System.Net Information: 0 : [5420] ConnectStream#33166512 - Sending headers

{

Proxy-Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==

Host: xxx.xxxxx.xx

Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

}.`

I want to get rid of the `Keep-Alive` and change it to `Close` but cannot find out how to control this header. How do I change or disable the `Proxy-Connection` header?

Edit:
Googleing around I figured that I have to set the `webRequest.Connection = "Close";` or `webRequest.Connection = null;`, but those results in an argument exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appareantly it is not possible to change the `Proxy-Connection` header.

The result that I was trying to achieve (close the tcp connection to the proxy before the load-balancer between client and proxy kills it after 2 minutes of inactivity) was realized by setting

`ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 100000;`

The `ServicePointManager` closes the underlying connection after 100 seconds, well before it is killed by the load-balancer and creates a new one when necessary.